# RxJava 2.x: serialize() doesn't work

Tags: rx-java2

I tried below to test the `sereialize()`.

I called `onNext` 1,000,000 times to count from 2 different threads.
Then, I expected to get 2,000,000 at `onComplete`.

However, I couldn't get the expected value.

```
private static int count = 0;

private static void setCount(int value) {
  count = value;
}

private static final int TEST_LOOP = 10;

private static final int NEXT_LOOP = 1_000_000;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

  for (int test = 0; test < TEST_LOOP; test++) {
    Flowable.create(emitter -> {
      ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      emitter.setCancellable(() -> service.shutdown());

      Future<Boolean> future1 = service.submit(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < NEXT_LOOP; i++) {
          emitter.onNext(i);
        }
        return true;
      });

      Future<Boolean> future2 = service.submit(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < NEXT_LOOP; i++) {
          emitter.onNext(i);
        }
        return true;
      });

      if (future1.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          && future2.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        emitter.onComplete();
      }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .serialize()
        .cast(Integer.class)
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {

          private int count = 0;

          @Override
          public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
          }

          @Override
          public void onNext(Integer t) {
            count++;
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(Throwable t) {
            fail(t.getMessage());
          }

          @Override
          public void onComplete() {
            setCount(count);
          }
        });

    assertThat(count, is(NEXT_LOOP * 2));
  }
}
```

I wonder whether `serialize()` doesn't work or I missunderstood the usage of `serialize()`

I checked the source of SerializedSubscriber.

```
@Override
public void onNext(T t) {
  ...
  synchronized(this){
    ...
  }
  actual.onNext(t);
  emitLoop();
}
```

Since `actual.onNext(t);` is called out of synchronized block, I guess that `actual.onNext(t);` could be called from different threads at the same time. Also, it may be possible to call `onComplete` before `onNext` would be done, I guess.

I used RxJava 2.0.4.

Comment: You should file a bug with the project: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/new

Comment: @spierce7 Before I make the issue, I want to make sure it a bug since there is a possbility of my misundaerstanding.of the usage. I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug but a [misuse](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/FlowableEmitter.html) of the `FlowableEmitter`:

> The onNext, onError and onComplete methods should be called in a sequential manner, just like the Subscriber's methods. Use [serialize()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/FlowableEmitter.html#serialize()) if you want to ensure this. The other methods are thread-safe.

`FlowableEmitter.serialize()`

Applying `Flowable.serialize()` is too late for the `create` operator.